# When I push to array, it pushes to another array also

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is JS:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('fooCtrl', function($scope){
    var fooProto = {
      arrayItems: [],
      addItem: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.arrayItems.push(new Date());
      }
    };
    $scope.fooes = [];
    $scope.foo1 = angular.extend({}, fooProto);
    $scope.foo2 = angular.extend({}, fooProto);
});
```

CodePen with HTML:
http://codepen.io/qn0361/pen/vXQqPG

How to escape from that?
Thank you!

Comment: All of those objects share the same array instance.  You can't do that.

Comment: Objects that are "copied" actually point at the _same_ object, so in general `arr1 = []; arr2 = arr1;` will be a single array and both `arr1` and `arr2` will reference that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have an object in which you have an array

```
 var fooProto = {
      arrayItems: [],
      addItem: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.arrayItems.push(new Date());
      }
    };
```

Array is a reference type.So when you copy your objects,it copies the properties, and if the property is a **reference type**, it **copies the reference**

```
$scope.foo1 = angular.extend({}, fooProto);
```

the `$scope.foo1` gets the **copy of the referenece**, they all refer to the same object. So you work with the same object by two references,which refer to the same `array`.

You can fix it with `constructor-function`

```
function foo(){
   this.arrayItems = [];
   this.addItem = function(){
      this.arrayItems.push(new Date());
   }
}

var foo1 = new foo();
var foo2 = new foo();
```

Here you will have two instances of `foo`, each of them has it's own `arrayItems`.

In your case you don't need to copy items, as I understand you do that for not copying but creating a new instance of that **'type'**.

Comment: Might mention the fix, i.e. giving each instance its own empty array in the constructor...

Comment: So I have to use array outside of proto and create it inside each particular instance?

Comment: @SergeyTyrtyshnikov see the updated part,I think you want that.